# How do i match below string using Regex in JavaScript? [Don't focus on duplicate, reviewer just was too judgemental]

Tags: javascript, regex

Here I want to get all classes as a string using regex.

- What will be a good regex to match the below string.

**Input String**

```
   <div class="container mx-5">
      <button class="btn btn-primary mt-auto mb-8 mx-8 justify-center">Sign In</button>
      <button class="btn btn-secondary mt-auto mb-8 mx-8 justify-center">Sign Out</button>
    </div>
```

**Expected Output from regex match**

```
['class="container mx-5"', 'class="btn btn-primary mt-auto mb-8 mx-8 justify-center"', 'class="btn btn-secondary mt-auto mb-8 mx-8 justify-center"']
```

Comment: If you want to get the class attribute of every element with a class attribute, use `[...document.querySelectorAll('[class]')].map(n=>n.getAttribute('class'))`. This won't include the `class="..."` wrapper but you can re-add that if you really want to.

Comment: "Expected Output from regex match" can you read? :) he want to

Comment: I can't do that, it's a runtime just in time compiler I am building for string find and replace functionality.

Answer (score 0):

if you need only that what follows after class="

```
class=\"[^\>]*
```

if you need only in class=""

```
class=\"[^\"]*\"
```

Comment: That would work, but i might have string like this as well
```
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-auto mb-8 mx-8 justify-center" id="test" type="test">Sign In</button>
```

and I want only class part of it.

Comment: so, when you asking you have to clarify your constraints if you need only in

Comment: humbly, that's why wrote the expected output as well.

Comment: but your input string didn't have that o[tions what you wrote in comments

Comment: And this is exactly why you don't use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @Pentiux, Second answer worked. Thanks, man.